# UITableView section header in editing mode only

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uitableview, uikit

The table view section headers in my plain (non-grouped) `UITableView` only appear when the table has been placed into editing mode. This is because I have two sections in the table view: Active and Inactive. I only wish the Active section to be displayed normally, but require both Active and Inactive to be displayed when in editing mode. Thus, having the section headers display when in editing mode allows the easy distinction between the two table view sections.

However, I am encountering the following problem. When the edit button is tapped (to place the `UITableView` into editing mode) the section headers are inserted and a strip of white space appears above each section in the `UITableView`. However, the header itself does not display - just white space which exactly matches the dimensions of the section header bar. If I scroll the `UITableView` (even ever so slightly, not even taking the section header space off-screen) the section header bar immediately appears. It almost seems like the `UITableView` is not repainting this space correctly.

The way that I have got the section headers to display in editing mode only is by placing an `if (self.tableView.editing) { }` statement in the `titleForHeaderInSection` delegate method.

I have tried doing a `[self.tableView reload]` and alike which does display the section headers correctly, but also eliminates the nice animation between editing and non-editing mode (which I obviously wish to keep).

Any ideas on how to resolve this strange problem would be much appreciated!

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this problem?

Comment: Hi Johan. Unfortunately not. Are you experiencing the same issue?

Answer (score 1):

The best I've been able to come up with is this:

```
[tableView reloadSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:0] 
         withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
```

The animation works, but it's not quite as nice as the default editing animation.

This assumes you want to reload the header/footer in section 0.